# Spacing between 2 responsive divs

Tags: html, css, responsive

newbie here. I'm trying to place a map and some text next to each other that will stack when in responsive mode.

Example of what I'm trying to achieve : www.visitessex.com/thedms.aspx?dms=3&venue=0486563 Please look at 'Location' and 'Directions'.

What I've done : http://jsfiddle.net/qs3frhb5/

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
<div class="inner"> Left </div>
<div class="inner"> Right </div>
</div>

.inner{
outline: 1px solid #333;
float: left;
width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width:500px){
.inner{
    width: 50%;
}
```

That snippet which I found on SO actually works well, but I'm having a slight problem. On desktop everything is fine - the map and text sit next to each other with good amount of spacing in between them.

However, on ipad, the map and text sit right next to each other with almost no spacing in between, making it look slightly weird.

I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. Basically I'd like the 2 divs to always have a little space between them when stacked side by side. Based on my limited understanding I believe it's a padding or width issue but can't figure out what to do.

Comment: use flex and margin on child maybe http://jsfiddle.net/qs3frhb5/60/ or table display + border-spacing http://jsfiddle.net/qs3frhb5/61/ .... the link shos a slider ?? is that what you try to do ?

Comment: Hi, I'm not trying to make the slider. Pls scroll down and look at the map and text next to it. That's what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: okay; forget float and width, use some display layout, grid can also be used http://jsfiddle.net/qs3frhb5/62/ links given shows 3 display ways (old to new) table, flex and grid. table will do fine from IE8 and old browsers . On mediaquerie, if the idea is to pile them, just reset things back to block http://jsfiddle.net/qs3frhb5/63/

Comment: Sorry, how do i stack those divs? Is it possible to make your solution responsive?

Comment: It is , via media queries (last fiddle is an example :) ) or even a min-width in flex case : http://jsfiddle.net/qs3frhb5/64/

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look as soon as I can. Appreciate your help!